# fullscreenJS moveTo method incorrect View

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, gsap

I am using [FullscreenJS](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) on a side project and I am having trouble using the moveTo method provided.

The moveTo is firing off, the anchor shows the correct slide, but the view doesn't change, it remains on the first section.

```
 $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('firstSlides');

 anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'firstSlides'],
```

The full definition.

```
 $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'Portfolio'],
        showActiveTooltip: true,
        sectionsColor: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'blue'],
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'firstSlides'],
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
          if (whichBoxIsOpen == 'third') {
            console.log(whichBoxIsOpen);
            $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('firstSlides');
          }
        }
      });
```

The full page can be found [here](http://codepen.io/dnwebdev/pen/rVRWje), to test please select '**Portfolio**' which is the third box, notice the view doesn't shift to the slides.

Update -added image
[image]

Comment: what is the your desired outcome here?

Comment: Notice when you select the top left box, the first section appears, when the bottom left box is selected, the slides should appear, instead what is happening is that the anchors on the right show that the slides appear, but the view does not reflect that.

Comment: could it be because you do not have `.fullScreenThree` element present in your HTML?

Comment: I have posted my answer. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is **[this](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/ZGNzyg/)** the kind of result you are expecting? Basically, I think all you needed was a little `setTimeout` in the `afterLoad` callback.

***JavaScript:***

```
...
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
  if (whichBoxIsOpen == 'third') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.fn.fullpage.moveTo('firstSlides');
    }, 1000);
  }
}
...
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: This works, I was hoping to use the following instead of sliding after it is loaded. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-links-to-sections-or-slides

Comment: Note - I don't think it's possible to do that within a codepen, might have to test it locally, if not I will accept this answer.

Comment: what is the difference? this example that you linked to also contains the same callbacks?

Comment: The example you provided moves the section after, what I would like (in theory) is to load the slider at the position desired, without moving it, using anchors.

Comment: Edit - after testing it, it looks like it moves after loaded. I will use silentMoveTo method and accept your answer.

Comment: that should be easy. give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: yup. I was going to use `silentMoveTo` method but I guess you already know that :)

Comment: If you believe it would be easy, that would be even better :)

Comment: So the issue is that the moveTo was firing off before the slides were available? is the setTimeouteven required since we are waiting until afterload?

Comment: Yes. `afterLoad` was firing twice but the display wasn't updated because slides just weren't there to begin with. We need a little time for them to appear first before we can do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Rkhayat,

I managed to keep your screen at one place but it looks a lot like your `TweenMax.to($fullScreenOne)` is a little messy. This [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNoxVm) contains my changes. I will keep playing with it here.

Comment: Hello @bobleujr, thanks for reaching out. It is my first time playing with GSAP so it is probably very messy, haha. I appreciate your assistance.